# How to Play RTMP Live Streaming in videoview url in android

Tags: android, streaming

I am trying to play rtmp live streaming url in android. How can do this. I know about rtsp but how can I do with rtmp.

Comment: Please show your current research effort.

Answer (score 1):

Use Webview to play that type of video because this type of video can't play in mediaplayer.